# Rails controller returning undefined method 'save', but saving anyway

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I've been struggling to get Omniauth with multiple providers to work for a couple of days now. I finally have it (mostly) working - Facebook and Twitter work as expected for syncing, however I'm having an issue with Steam.

```
class AuthenticationsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :steam

  def index
    @authentications = current_user.authentications.all
  end
  # <%= link_to 'Authentications', authentications_path %>
  def home
  end

  def twitter
     omni = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
     authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omni['provider'], omni['uid'])

     if authentication
      flash[:notice] = "Logged in Successfully"
      sign_in_and_redirect User.find(authentication.user_id)
     elsif current_user
      token = omni['credentials'].token
      token_secret = omni['credentials'].secret

      current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omni['provider'], 
                                          :uid => omni['uid'], 
                                          :token => token, 
                                          :token_secret => token_secret)
      flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
      sign_in_and_redirect current_user
     else
      user = User.new
      user.apply_omniauth(omni)
      raise user.inspect
      if user.save
         flash[:notice] = "Logged in."
         sign_in_and_redirect User.find(user.id)             
      else
         session[:omniauth] = omni.except('extra')
         redirect_to new_user_registration_path
      end
     end 
   end

   def destroy
     @authentication = Authentication.find(params[:id])
     @authentication.destroy
     redirect_to authentications_url, :notice => "Successfully destroyed authentication."
   end


   def facebook
     omni = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
     authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omni['provider'], omni['uid'])

     if authentication
      flash[:notice] = "Logged in Successfully"
      sign_in_and_redirect User.find(authentication.user_id)
     elsif current_user
      token = omni['credentials'].token
      token_secret = ""

      current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omni['provider'], 
                                           :uid => omni['uid'], 
                                           :token => token, 
                                           :token_secret => token_secret)

      flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
      sign_in_and_redirect current_user
     else
      user = User.new
      user.email = omni['extra']['raw_info'].email 

      user.apply_omniauth(omni)

      if user.save
         flash[:notice] = "Logged in."
         sign_in_and_redirect User.find(user.id)             
      else
         session[:omniauth] = omni.except('extra')
         redirect_to new_user_registration_path
      end
     end
   end

    def steam
        omni = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
        authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omni['provider'], omni['uid'])

        if authentication
            flash[:notice] = "Logged in Successfully"
            sign_in_and_redirect User.find(authentication.user_id)
        elsif current_user
        token = omni['extra']['raw_info'].steamid
        # render :text => request.env["omniauth.auth"].info.to_hash.inspect

        puts token
        token_secret = ""

            current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omni['provider'], 
                                                 :uid => omni['uid'], 
                                                 :token => token, 
                                                 :token_secret => token_secret)
            flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
            sign_in_and_redirect current_user
        else
            user = User.new
            user.apply_omniauth(omni)
        end

        if user.save
            flash[:notice] = "Logged in."
            sign_in_and_redirect User.find(user.id)             
        else
            session[:omniauth] = omni.except('extra')
            redirect_to new_user_registration_path
        end
    end




end
```

As you can see the `twitter` function and `steam` are almost duplicates - They reference a function within the `User model` which is

```
def apply_omniauth(omni)
    authentications.build(:provider => omni['provider'], 
                          :uid => omni['uid'],
                          :token => omni['credentials'].token, 
                          :token_secret => omni['credentials'].secret)
  end
```

Currently Steam will respond with `undefined method 'save' for nil`
on

```
if user.save
    flash[:notice] = "Logged in."
    sign_in_and_redirect User.find(user.id)             
else
```

What's confusing me is it IS actually saving.

```
 => #<Authentication id: 12, provider: "steam", uid: "redacted", token: "76561198038103683", token_secret: "", created_at: "2017-07-18 14:57:32", updated_at: "2017-07-18 14:57:32", user_id: 2> 
2.4.1 :022 > u.authentications.last.destroy
  Authentication Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "authentications".* FROM "authentications" WHERE "authentications"."user_id" = $1 ORDER BY "authentications"."id" DESC LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.6ms)  DELETE FROM "authentications" WHERE "authentications"."id" = $1  [["id", 13]]
   (4.2ms)  COMMIT
 => #<Authentication id: 13, provider: "steam", uid: "redacted", token: "redacted", token_secret: "", created_at: "2017-07-18 15:13:00", updated_at: "2017-07-18 15:13:00", user_id: 2> 
2.4.1 :023 > u.authentications.last
  Authentication Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "authentications".* FROM "authentications" WHERE "authentications"."user_id" = $1 ORDER BY "authentications"."id" DESC LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Authentication id: 14, provider: "steam", uid: "redacted", token: "redacted", token_secret: "", created_at: "2017-07-18 15:13:19", updated_at: "2017-07-18 15:13:19", user_id: 2>
```

I delete the record - Then go re-auth, and get the same error, but the relation does exist.

I'm not sure how to print out `user` to see what it happening to it, or how to bug test within this at all.

Any feedback is welcome, been a long couple of days for this gem.

Answer (score 0):

So you are setting `user` variable only in `else` branch. If any other branch is evaluated `user` variable is nil. Just move last if (`if user.save`) into `else` branch of second if:

```
  def steam
    omni = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omni['provider'], omni['uid'])

    if authentication
        flash[:notice] = "Logged in Successfully"
        sign_in_and_redirect User.find(authentication.user_id)
    elsif current_user
    token = omni['extra']['raw_info'].steamid
    # render :text => request.env["omniauth.auth"].info.to_hash.inspect

    puts token
    token_secret = ""

        current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omni['provider'], 
                                             :uid => omni['uid'], 
                                             :token => token, 
                                             :token_secret => token_secret)
        flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
        sign_in_and_redirect current_user
    else
        user = User.new
        user.apply_omniauth(omni)
        if user.save
          flash[:notice] = "Logged in."
          sign_in_and_redirect User.find(user.id)             
        else
          session[:omniauth] = omni.except('extra')
          redirect_to new_user_registration_path
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I didn't think about it like that, but I get it. What I'm struggling with, it is technically shouldn't be hitting that `else`. When it syncs me, it's hitting the `elsif current_user` and then also continuing down. I'm new-ish to rails but I don't get why it's doing the elsif and then also doing the else.

Comment: You are not doing `else` :) You are doing next `if` because `sign_in_and_redirect` doesn't stop the rest of the code from execution. If you would add `return` after this method next if would not be executed.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I kind of get it, but not completely. I tried doing the return above 'else' and above if user.save, and I'm still getting an error on user.save - Could you show me an example of what you're implying?